# How to split CSV column data into two colums in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have the following code (below) that grabs to CSV files and merges data into one consolidated CSV file.

I now need to grab specific information from one of the columns add that information to another column.

What I have now is one output.csv file with the following sample data:

```
ID,Name,Flavor,RAM,Disk,VCPUs
45fc754d-6a9b-4bde-b7ad-be91ae60f582,customer1-test1-dns,m1.medium,4096,40,2
83dbc739-e436-4c9f-a561-c5b40a3a6da5,customer2-test2,m1.tiny,128,1,1
ef68fcf3-f624-416d-a59b-bb8f1aa2a769,customer3-test3-dns-api,m1.medium,4096,40,2
```

What I need to do is open this CSV file and split the data in the Name column across two columns as followed:

```
ID,Name,Flavor,RAM,Disk,VCPUs,Customer,Misc
45fc754d-6a9b-4bde-b7ad-be91ae60f582,customer1-test1-dns,m1.medium,4096,40,2,customer1,test1-dns
83dbc739-e436-4c9f-a561-c5b40a3a6da5,customer2-test2,m1.tiny,128,1,1,customer2,test2
ef68fcf3-f624-416d-a59b-bb8f1aa2a769,customer3-test3-dns-api,m1.medium,4096,40,2,customer3,test3-dns-api
```

Note how the Misc column can have multiple values split by one or multiple `-`.

How can I accomplish this via Python. Below is the code I have now:

```
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd

by_name = {}
with open('flavor.csv') as b:
    for row in csv.DictReader(b):
        name = row.pop('Name')
        by_name[name] = row

with open('output.csv', 'w') as c:
    w = csv.DictWriter(c, ['ID', 'Name', 'Flavor', 'RAM', 'Disk', 'VCPUs'])
    w.writeheader()

    with open('instance.csv') as a:
        for row in csv.DictReader(a):
            try:
                match = by_name[row['Flavor']]
            except KeyError:
                continue

            row.update(match)

            w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Are you using the library `csv` over `pandas` because `pandas` doesn't work or because you're more familiar with the library `csv`? If `pd.read_csv("'flavor.csv'")` works, I can refer to an example that utilizes `pandas` entirely.

Comment: I am using csv exclusively at the moment. I am not very familiar with pandas but most solutions I found online called for panda so I imported it with the intent of using it moving forward. Its currently not being used though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('flavor.csv')
df[['Customer','Misc']] = df.Name.str.split('-', n=1, expand=True)
df
```

**Output:**

```
                                     ID                     Name     Flavor   RAM  Disk  VCPUs   Customer           Misc
0  45fc754d-6a9b-4bde-b7ad-be91ae60f582      customer1-test1-dns  m1.medium  4096    40      2  customer1      test1-dns
1  83dbc739-e436-4c9f-a561-c5b40a3a6da5          customer2-test2    m1.tiny   128     1      1  customer2          test2
2  ef68fcf3-f624-416d-a59b-bb8f1aa2a769  customer3-test3-dns-api  m1.medium  4096    40      2  customer3  test3-dns-api
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching over to `pandas`. Here's the official [Getting Started documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html).

Let's first read in the csv.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

print(df.head(1))
```

You should get something similar to:

```
ID  Name    Flavor  RAM Disk    VCPUs
0   45fc754d-6a9b-4bde-b7ad-be91ae60f582    customer1-test1-dns m1.medium   4096    40  2
```

After that, use string manipulation in the Pandas Series:

```
df[['Customer','Misc']] = df.Name.str.split('-', n=1, expand=True)
```

Finally, you can save the csv.

```
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

This code would be much elegant and simpler if you used pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('flavor.csv')

df[['Customer','Misc']] = df['Name'].str.split(pat='-',n=1,expand=True)

df.to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

[Documentation ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it. The trick is in the function "split()" :

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv(r"C:\...\yourfile.csv",sep=",")

file['Customer']=None
file['Misc']=None
for x in range(len(file)):
    temp=file.Name[x].split('-', maxsplit=1)
    file['Customer'].iloc[x] = temp[0]
    file['Misc'].iloc[x] = temp[1]

file.to_csv(r"C:\...\yourfile_result.csv")
```